# How to create a weighted composite covariance function using GPML toolbox in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, covariance, gpflow, gaussian-process

I'm trying to create a composite covariance function to model my data. Specifically I want to create a kernel which is weighted between `@covSEard` & `@covRQard`. For ex: I want to give a 30% weight to `@covSEard` & 70% to `@covRQard`, something like `0.3*@covSEard + 0.7*@covRQard`

I tried the following options.

**Option 1 - Using the `@covSum` & `@covProd` functionalities**

```
input_dimensions = 4; % number of input dimensions
seed = 1234; % seed for reproducibility
rng(seed);
X = rand(100, input_dimensions); % sample input data generation
y = rand(100, 1); % sample output data generation

addpath(genpath(PATH_TO_GPML_TOOLBOX)); % adding gpml toolbox to the path

meanFunc = {@meanZero}; % using a zero mean
meanHyp = {[]}; % zero mean has no hyper parameters

kernel_weight = 0.3; % weight of covSEard kernel, 0.7 will be the weight for covRQard kernel

% defining the covariance function as a weighted sum of covSEard & covRQard
covFunc = {'covSum', {{'covProd', {'covConst','covSEard'}}, {'covProd', {'covConst','covRQard'}}}};

% variables to define the hyperparameters for the above kernel
sf=2; L=rand(input_dimensions,1); al=2; 

% Covariance function for a constant function. The covariance function is parameterized as:
% k(x,z) = sf^2
% 
% The scalar hyperparameter is:
% hyp = [ log(sf) ]
covHyp = {log([sqrt(kernel_weight); L; sf; sqrt(1-kernel_weight); L; sf; al])};

likFunc = {@likGauss}; % Using a gaussian likelihood
likHyp = {-1}; % Likelihood hyper parameter initialization

infMethod= @infGaussLik; % Using Gaussian inference
iters = -300; % Number of iterations for Bayesian Optimization


% Defining the hyper parameter struct
hyp.lik = cell2mat(likHyp(1));
hyp.cov = cell2mat(covHyp(1));
hyp.mean = cell2mat(meanHyp(1));

% Defining mean, covariance and likelihood functions
mF = meanFunc{1,1}; cF=covFunc; lF=likFunc{1,1};
hyp2vfe = minimize(hyp, @gp, iters, infMethod, mF, cF, lF, X, y); % Optimization of hyperparameters / Training
[nll, ~] = gp(hyp2vfe, infMethod, mF, cF, lF, X, y); % Negative Log Likelihood calculation
```

Here, I'm trying to use the `@covConst` kernel which has only the signal variance hyper-parameter which I'm forcing to be equal to the weight (Ex: 0.3 for `@covSEard` & 0.7 for `@covRQard` in this case.
However, when I try to optimize the above kernel's hyper parameters, even the weights (which are actually the hyper parameters of the `@covConst` kernel are also getting modified.

**Option 2 - Using the `@covSum` functionality and repeating each kernel n times based on weight**

For example, if I want to give 1:2 weights to `@covSEard` & `@covRQard` respectively, I would do the following

replace the following lines in the above code

`covFunc = {'covSum', {{'covProd', {'covConst','covSEard'}}, {'covProd', {'covConst','covRQard'}}}};`
with
`covfunc = {'covSum', {'covSEard', 'covRQard', 'covRQard'}};`

&

`covHyp = {log([sqrt(kernel_weight); L; sf; sqrt(1-kernel_weight); L; sf; al])};`
with
`covHyp = {log([L; sf; L; sf; al; L; sf; al])};`

However, in this case the number of hyper parameters would increase linearly and also I'm not sure if this is the right way to do things.

I want to know what is the correct way to create such a covariance function in GPML. Please suggest.